# .jtl file is generating in wrong format

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

JTL file is generating as comma separated value instead of binary.Let me know whether i have to change any configuration.ALso headers are not generating in the comma separated format

```
1619678537202,1180,Login,200,OK,OutletUpload_MDM 7-1,text,true,,74563,2008,1,1,https://devuitest.bizomdev.in/users/dashboard,788,0,578
1619678537202,788,Login-0,302,Found,OutletUpload_MDM 7-1,text,true,,1755,713,1,1,https://devuitest.bizomdev.in//users/login,788,0,578
1619678537998,120,Login-1,302,Found,OutletUpload_MDM 7-1,text,true,,1628,640,1,1,https://devuitest.bizomdev.in/,120,0,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter result files have never been binary, the options are in [t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), both are text.

There is no "right" or "wrong" format, you can control what and how to store using properties responsible for the [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

If you need to save request and response headers you will need the following amendments:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
```

Place the above lines into [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and next time you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) - the result file will be in XML format and contain request and response headers.